# Estimation of the number of terms required to evaluate an infinite series function up to a given precision

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function, truncation-error

Consider the following series function defined in terms of an infinite series of the form
$$
f(x,y) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty f_m(x,y) ,
$$
where
$$
f_m(x,y) = (2m+2)(2m+3)(2m+5) \, \Gamma \left( m + 7/2 \right)^{-2} \,
{}_2F_1 \left( -m, -m-1/2; 2; x^2 \right) y^{2m} \, .
$$
Here, $\Gamma$ is the gamma function and ${}_2F_1$ is Gauss hypergeometric function.

To evaluate the function numerically up to a given precision, the series needs to be truncated after a certain number of terms.
While for $x \to \infty$ and $m \to \infty$, I was able to show that
$$
f_n(x,y) \sim \frac{8}{\pi^{3/2}} \left( \frac{xy \, \mathrm{e}}{m} \right)^{2m}
m^{-7/2} \, ,
$$
I have no idea how to estimate the numbers of terms required to achieve a given precision.
Any input is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you focused only on the large $x$ asymptotic regime, so that your asymptotic expression is actually useful? (Thankfully, the dependence on $y$ is relatively simple so I don't have an analogous question about that.)

Comment: @Ian That would also be something useful and good to know. Apparently for $x \gg 1$, the asymptotic expansion looks quite promising. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just look at the series $\sum_{m=1}^\infty C (xye/m)^{2m} m^{-7/2}$ (discarding the $m=0$ term since the asymptotic is singular there), you can use the same kind of estimates that are used to prove the ratio test. Specifically, once $(xye/M)<\epsilon<1$ and $M>0$, you have

$$\sum_{m=M}^\infty C (xye/m)^{2m} m^{-7/2}<\sum_{m=M}^\infty C \epsilon^{2m}=C \frac{\epsilon^{2M}}{1-\epsilon^2}.$$